# Misleading documentation on BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-intent

Does anyone know what this line supposed to mean in the Android documentation ([enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)): "

> Note:    If registering a receiver in your Activity.onResume() implementation, you should unregister it in Activity.onPause(). (You won't receive intents when paused, and this will cut down on unnecessary system overhead).

The first sentence is clear, one should release resources if they aren't needed. But what about the bracketed text? Apparently an app in the background receives the broadcast intents if it is stopped (At least on Android 4.2). It won't get the broadcast when it is destroyed. Code to try:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;

    String a = "1234";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("|BR", "onReceive() - 1"  + " intent: " + intent);
                a = intent.getStringExtra("ASDF");
            }
        };
        this.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyService.RECEIVE));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("|BR", "onResume()" + " a: " + a);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("|BR", "onPause()");
    }

    /** Event handler for a button in the main.xml */
    public void createService(View view) {
        Log.d("|BR", "createService()");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyService.DO);
        this.startService(intent);
    }
}


public class MyService extends Service {

    public static final String DO = MyService.class.getName() + ".DO";
    public static final String RECEIVE = MyService.class.getName() + ".RECEIVE";

    public Executor executor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        Log.d("|BR", "onStartCommand() - 1");
        if(DO.equals(action)) {
            executor.execute(new MyRunnable());
            Log.d("|BR", "onStartCommand() - 2");

        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public android.os.IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("|BR", "run() - 1");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 8);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Log.d("|BR", "run() - 2");

            Intent intent = new Intent(RECEIVE);
            intent.putExtra("ASDF", "QWER");
            MyService.this.sendBroadcast(intent);

            Log.d("|BR", "run() - 3");

        }
    }
}
```

Press the button, press home button, wait 8 seconds. Result:

```
09:05:48.622    D/|BR: onResume() a: 1234
09:05:53.297    D/|BR: createService()
09:05:53.297    D/|BR: onStartCommand() - 1
09:05:53.307    D/|BR: onStartCommand() - 2
09:05:53.307    D/|BR: run() - 1
09:05:54.558    D/|BR: onPause()
09:06:01.306    D/|BR: run() - 2
09:06:01.316    D/|BR: onReceive() - 1 intent: Intent { act=com.example.broadcastReceive.MyService.RECEIVE flg=0x10 (has extras) }
09:06:01.316    D/|BR: run() - 3
09:06:14.139    D/|BR: onResume() a: QWER
```

Comment: I don't understand how it is misleading. Your app is in pause, and you receive a broadcast because your receiver is not unregistered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means that you won't receive broadcasts if you've unregistered the `BroadcastReceiver` in your `onPause()`.

Comment: Aw. So the bracketed text is the result of the onPause() and not the result of being in the background. That makes sense. My world is in place now again. Thanks. (Still I think it is a bit misleading).

Answer (score 0):

Dependening on what you do in the receiver, it might be very CPU/Battery consuming. If it is, you want it to be executed as rarely as possible and thats what this sentence wants to say.

Have you ever ran code, that receives GPS information? It lets your battery live for at max 2 hours. So, every second counts, when this is switched on. `onResume` and `onPause` are best places to turn on/off this feature. Using `onStart`, `onStop` or even `onCreate`, `onDestroy` would mean, that the feature is turned on (and consumes battery) longer then necessary.